# How to Combine AND and OR Condition in the Enrty Criteria for Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder

How to combine AND and OR condition in the entry criteria for Process Builder? for Opportunity stage I would like to combine AND & OR condition for entry criteria, but PB has only options like, all of the conditions are met (AND), Any of the conditions are met (OR), Customize the logic => about this option I don't know. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: create multiple steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eric has suggested to create a multiple steps and then you can use a third option "Customize Logic"

[image]

Check [Customize the Condition Logic in Process Builder](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_process_filter.htm) as a reference